# Change page contents with AJAX after submiting a popup form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, popup

I have this problem that in order to change the page contents I have to receive user input. I want to do this via popup form. After clicking the button "submit" on the popup I want to send the form input to a `php` file where I connect to the database and send the retrieved information via JSON  to the `js` file where I use a `$.post()` method to achieve all this. The problem is that insted of the page contents being changed without reload I get redirected to a page `http://localhost/statistics.php?major=KN&year=2011` but I want to stay on the page `http://localhost/statistics.php`. That is why I am using AJAX in the first place. `major=KN` & `year=2011` are my POST parameters. Is it possible to change the contents of a page after submitting a popup form? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code that I think could be relevant to solving the issue:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="ch/Chart.js"></script>
            <script src="js/statistics_js.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="abc">
                <div id="popupContact">
                    <form id="form1" name="form1">
                        <img class="close" src="images/3.png" onclick ="div_hide_group_popup()">
                        <h2>Fill the form</h2>
                        <hr>
                        <input name="major" placeholder="Major" type="text">
                        <input name="year" placeholder="Year" type="number">
                        <button id="submit1">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="page">
                <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
            </div>
            <aside>
                <h3>Compare</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li id="group"><a href="#">groups</a></li>
                </ul>
            </aside>
        </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The `js/statistics_js.js` file:

```
    function error(){
        alert('Error!');
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#group').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "block";
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit1").click( function() {
            $.post( "http://localhost/group_sort.php", $("#form1").serialize(), "JSON").done(function(data) {
                    //This should use the Chart.js library to draw a chart on the canvas with the data retrieved from the server.
                    var barChartData = {
                        labels : data.groups,
                        datasets : [
                            {
                                fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                                strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
                                highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
                                highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                                data : data.groups_total_points
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
                    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
                        responsive : true
                    });
                }).error(error);
        });
    });

    function div_hide_group_popup(){
        document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "none";
    }
```

My `group_sort.php`:

```
    <?php
        require "config.php";
        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_SERVER . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            die("Database connection could not be established.");
        }
        $conn->exec("SET NAMES UTF8");
        $major = $_POST['major'];
        $year = $_POST['year'];
        $sql = "SELECT result.group, SUM(result.grade) AS group_total_points
                FROM (
                    SELECT *
                    FROM students AS s
                    INNER JOIN points AS p
                    ON s.fn = p.student_fn
                ) result
                WHERE result.major = '$major' AND result.year = '$year'
                GROUP BY result.group
                ORDER BY group_total_points DESC";
        $query = $conn->query($sql);
        if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
            $data = array (
                "groups" => [],
                "groups_total_points" => [],
                );
            while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $data["groups"][] = $row["group"];
                $data["groups_total_points"][] = $row["group_total_points"];
            }
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
        else {
            echo mysql_error();
        }

        $conn = null;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your submit button is probably submitting the form when you click it. Prevent the default action on click:

```
    $("#submit1").click( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post( "http://localhost/group_sort.php", $("#form1").serialize(), "JSON").done(function(data) {
```

Comment: That is what it is supposed to do - to send the input from the form to the `php` file. Now that I did what you said though I got an alert "Error" from the `error()` function. Any idea how to see where it comes from?

Comment: No, you want to get the input via Ajax, not submit the form. What was probably happening was that your form was getting submitted, the page was refreshing, and your Ajax call was never being acted upon. When you prevent the default, your Ajax code IS being used and is getting an error. What is the error message?

Comment: It is just "Error!" because that's what the body of my `error()` method is. Any idea how to change it so that I get the actual error?

Comment: The error is `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/group_sort.php"` but I have a file named like that...

Comment: The file just wasn't where it was supposed to. Otherwise you were right about `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your submit button is completing the submit.  I would recommend changing it to a normal button to prevent submitting, although they would be able to hit enter and submit the form.  For that you have to block the submit functionality of the form.

The simpler solution is to replace the form with a simple div:

```
<div class="form">
   <img class="close" src="images/3.png" onclick ="div_hide_group_popup()">
   <h2>Fill the form</h2>
   <hr>
   <input class="submit-form" name="major" placeholder="Major" type="text">
   <input class="submit-form" name="year" placeholder="Year" type="number">
   <button id="submit1">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Then with jquery you can select the form elements in the document.ready callback:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var input = $('input.submit-form');
    $("#submit1").click( function() {
        $.post( 
             "http://localhost/group_sort.php", 
             input.serialize(), 
             "JSON").done(function(data) { //...
```